# Как проверить устройство на наличие приложения?

Tags: swift, webview, swift3, swift4

Всем доброго времени суток. Нужно переходить с приложения на соц сети по нажатию кнопки. Если на телефоне юзера установлено приложение соц сетей, переходить в него, если нет то в сафари. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как проверить на наличие установленных приложений устройство и если они установлены, как подгружать через них юрл?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверить наличие стороннего приложения на iOS невозможно.
Вы можете использовать deeplink, чтобы открыть Safari и дать пользователю выбор - открыть приложение или сайт.